# Sorting a list by multiple non-standard criteria

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to set up a certain data structure in my program that takes the data from an excel file. It needed to be sorted by the following criteria:

1. Accending order by index 5.
2. If two structures have the same value for index 5, put the one which has index 0 = 8 to be listed first.

Currently, I've been able to sort by accending order by index 5 to turn this:

```
[8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 250]
[8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50]
[8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 25]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 60]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 30]
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 5]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 70]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 35]
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 8]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 80]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 40]
[4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 10]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 90]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 45]
[5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 12]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50]
[6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 15]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 120]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 60]
[9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 20]
[9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 150]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 75]
[10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 25]
[10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 400]
[11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 150]
[11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 40]
[11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

into this

```
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 400]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 250]
[11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 150]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 150]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 120]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 90]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 80]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 75]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 70]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 60]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 60]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50]
[8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 45]
[11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 40]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 40]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 35]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 30]
[10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 25]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 25]
[9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 20]
[6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 15]
[5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 12]
[4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 10]
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 8]
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 5]
[8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4]
[11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

This uses the `.sort(key = lambda x:x[5])` and `.reverse()` functions.

However, drawing attention to one section in particular.

```
[6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50]
[8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50]
```

I would like to anything with an 8 at index 0 to be the first listed, so this should be

```
[8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50]
```

I'm aware that in this specific case, this could be accomplished by doing a secondary sort on index 0 to get the desired result. However, there may be cases with different inputs where we may have, say

```
[6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50]
[8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50]
[11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 50]
```

which would need to be sorted to

```
[8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50]
[11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 50]
```

So doing a sort on a secondary variable wouldn't work. Where can i start to look for a solution to this particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use data.sort(key = lambda x:x[0] == 8), then it will sort every one with 8 on the position 0 to the last place. So what you could do would be the following:

First sort them, so all the 8 at the position 0 are on the end:

```
data.sort(key = lambda x:x[0] == 8)
```

Then sort based on the position 5:

```
data.sort(key = lambda x:x[5])
```

And then reverse the order:

```
data.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
l = [[8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 250],    [8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50],    [8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5],    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50],    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 25],    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4],    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 60],    [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 30],    [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 5],    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 70],    [3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 35],    [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 8],    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 80],    [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 40],    [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 10],    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 90],    [5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 45],    [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 12],    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100],    [6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50],    [6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 15],    [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 120],    [9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 60],    [9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 20],    [9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2],    [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 150],    [10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 75],    [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 25],    [10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 3],    [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 400],    [11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 150],    [11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 40],    [11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3], [11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 50]]

ls = sorted(l, key = lambda x: [x[5], x[0]==8], reverse = True)
```

Gives output as :

```
[[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 400], [8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 250], [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 150], [11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 150], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 120], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 90], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 80], [10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 75], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 70], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 60], [9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 60], [8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50], [6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50], [11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 50], [5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 45], [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 40], [11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 40], [3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 35], [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 30], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 25], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 25], [9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 20], [6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 15], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 12], [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 10], [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 8], [8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5], [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 5], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4], [10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 3], [11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3], [9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2]]
```

It sorts based on the fifth item of the list as first priority and if they are equal, check for the second priority - whether first item of the list is 8 (puts the list with 8 at first index at first, then the rest in sorted order of first item) like :

```
 [8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 50],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50],
 [6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 50],
 [11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 50],
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, this solves this particular problem , however, if we change `[11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 40]` to `[11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 50]`, then this sort would not output the desired result.